# Warning on github actions build for .netcore 6

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, .net-6.0

I have converted my project from .netcore3.1 to 6. We use github action for our builds. I changed the github actions files to use .net6 and the build works fine but I am getting the following warning and not sure how tofix it. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Warning: ... publish: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.203/Current/SolutionFile/ImportAfter/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(36,5): warning NETSDK1194: The "--output" option isn't supported when building a solution. Specifying a solution-level output path results in all projects copying outputs to the same directory, which can lead to inconsistent builds.

My .yml file is as follows

```
name: Lambda Image Build (CI)
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - main
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: '0'
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
      - name: Test
        run:  dotnet test
        working-directory: MyProject.Tests
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5
        with:
          nuget-version: latest
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
        working-directory: MyProject
      - name: Install dotnet lambda
        run: dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
        working-directory: MyProject
      - name: Build
        env:
          TAG_VERSION: ${{ steps.bump_version.outputs.new_tag }}
        run: dotnet lambda package .lambda/$( echo ${{ github.repository }} | cut -f 2 -d '/' ).zip s3://${{ secrets.S3_BUCKET }}/$( echo ${{ github.repository }} | cut -f 2 -d '/' )/${{ github.sha }}/$( echo ${{ github.repository }} | cut -f 2 -d '/' ).zip
        working-directory: MyProject
      - name: CHECK
        run: ls -al; echo $REPO_NAME;
        env:
          REPO_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}
        working-directory: ./
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "--output" option isn't supported when building a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548945/the-output-option-isnt-supported-when-building-a-solution)

Comment: @Azeem- I did read that post but I am not sure where to use this option "--property:PublishDir=DIR"? Could you please eleborate

Comment: Which step is issuing that warning in your workflow?

Comment: Your project file configuration may be needed. Please include its relevant output directory config in your question as well.

Comment: It's the build step

Comment: Just checked `dotnet lambda package --help` (version 5.6.6) and there's this `--msbuild-parameters` command line parameter that may be used to pass this configuration to `dotnet publish` command internally e.g. `dotnet lambda package --msbuild-parameters="--property:PublishDir=DIR"`.

Comment: @Azeem-thanks you so much, will check and update the results here!

Comment: @Azeem tried that unfortunately still outputs the same warning

Comment: Right. It's internal to `dotnet lambda`. You should [create an issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/new/choose) on its repo with all the details including what you tried with `--msbuild-parameters`.